# Проблема с определением Mercusys MU6H [Решено]

Tags: linux, debian

OC: Debian 10
Kernel: 4.19.0-18-686-pae
Device: Mercusys MU6H

Необходимо было подключить данный свисток к ПК. Поставил драйвер версии rtl8821CU, установился нормально. При этом в выводе `ip a` остались только два сетевых интерфейса: local и Ethernet. `dmesg` утверждает, что это диск:

```
usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=1a2b, bcdDevice= 2.00
usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-5: Product: DISK
usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
```

Вывод `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Можно ли как-то заставить ОС видеть адаптер как "сетевое устройство", а не как "накопитель"?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась переходом на Debian 11 и обновлением ядра до 5.10. Как я понял, ядро серии 4.19 не поддерживается дровами 8821cu в принципе.